# Why regex match result diffrent when using Text.Regex.Posix on ubuntu and windows,is that a bug?

Tags: regex, haskell

[image]

I write code above: left run on 32 bit ubuntu 16 in a virtualbox machine, right run on 64bit windows winghci.

The code is same, the result is different. Is that a bug?

Comment: Please post code replace of snapshot.

Comment: `Text.Regex.Posix` is backed by the C POSIX API. What are you using to give Windows POSIX functionality? Cygwin?

Comment: but I can got right result on windows:Prelude> :m +Text.Regex.Posix
Prelude Text.Regex.Posix> "abc"=~"a[a-z]+"::Bool
True

Comment: The voting on this question seems unusually harsh. Sure the code snippets are images instead of text, but they're so short it almost doesn't matter. And the question content follows all the usual rules: there's a minimal reproducing example with clear effort made to make the issue as small as possible, a clear, objective, answerable question attached... I don't really understand all the downvotes.

Comment: It is most probably due to the `+` quantifier: on Ubuntu, it seems that the POSIX syntax used is ERE, and on Windows, it looks like BRE. Try `"a\\s\\+"` on Windows. If it does not work, then the reason is that the regex library on Windows is a kind of a BSD grep that does not support `+` quantifier at all and is a very limited regex library. So, the `"a\\s\\s*"` pattern should work the same on both platforms.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the OP said that `"abc"=~"a[a-z]+"::Bool` works on Windows, so the `+` quantifier must be working.  Maybe the `\s` is not recognizing the space?  Try to match a single space with a pattern of `\s` and no quantifiers.

Comment: @pat I agree I might not have understood what was not working, Windows or Linux version. If the problem is with `\s`, and it can, then `[[:blank:]]` or `[[:space:]]` should be used instead of `\s`. And I'd rather use `"abc"=~"a[[:space:]][[:space:]]*"::Bool` to play it safe. If `"abc"=~"a[[:space:]]+"::Bool` works, cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a POSIX regex flavor, to match any whitespace chars, use `[[:space:]]` bracket expression with a *space* POSIX character class inside it:

```
Prelude Text.Regex.Posix> "a "=~"a[[:space:]]+" :: String
"a "
```

The `\s` shorthand character class comes from Perl, and you may use your pattern with the [*Text.Regex.PCRE*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-pcre-0.94.4/docs/Text-Regex-PCRE.html) library.