# Matching numbers with an optional delimiter in between

Tags: regex

So i got this regex code `/[0-3][0-9][0-1][1-9]\d{2}[-\s]\d{4}?[^0-9]*|[0-3][0-9][0-1][1-9]\d{2}\d{4}/`

This regex code take this kind of numbers:

```
1002821187
100282 1187
100282-1187
```

But i found out i dont want the numbers: `1002821187`

So is it possible to make 1 regex code that only finds:

```
100282 1187
100282-1187
```

Comment: Have you tried [(100282 1187 100282-1187)]?

Comment: See the parts of the regex on either side of the `|`? Try each side and find out what it matches.

Comment: El0din that is not a regex code :P

Comment: Ryan have tried that, but cant seem to get it working

Comment: See my answer for a correct solution.

Comment: The voting on this question seems unusually harsh. Sure initially the sample strings were concatenated due to poor formatting, but anyone can click *edit* and see the real text. And the question content follows all the usual rules: there's a minimal reproducing example, non-working regex is supplied and what is wrong with it is explained, input texts, what is valid and what is not, it is clear. It is not a "gimme-teh-regex" question,  like a lot of regex questions we see every day.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex contains an alternation that matches the numbers with and without the space or `-`. You need to require that space or hyphen:

```
^[0-3][0-9][0-1][1-9][0-9]{2}[-\s][0-9]{4}$
                             ^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ImpkCu/2). If you do not need to check for any boundaries, remove `^` and `$` anchors that make the pattern match the whole string and use `[0-3][0-9][0-1][1-9][0-9]{2}[-\s][0-9]{4}`. Or use word boundaries to find whole words, `\b[0-3][0-9][0-1][1-9][0-9]{2}[-\s][0-9]{4}\b`.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-3]` - a digit from `0` to `3`
- `[0-9]` - any digit
- `[0-1]` (=`[01]`) - `0` or `1`
- `[1-9]` - any digit other than `0`
- `[0-9]{2}` - 2 digits
- `[-\s]` - a `-` or whitespace
- `[0-9]{4}` - 4 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Not sure why the down vote on this. Maybe explain yourself? +1

Comment: @Frederik.L I think it is not because of the answer, the downvoter does not like the question. Although in **my** opinion, the question is a valid SO question, it was just formatted poorly and I fixed the formatting. Sometimes, people are too harsh on those who post poorly formatted questions (see [another question that got -2 for bad formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721860/why-regex-match-result-diffrent-when-using-text-regex-posix-on-ubuntu-and-window)).

Comment: Probably better to close vote instead of just down vote, and not to attack answers. I've come across this preventive close vote idea after asking this [question about poorly written questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353833/preventing-new-users-from-answering-poor-questions). I don't know if that should also apply to bad formatting. I think people get mad when OP doesn't seem to try being professional and want him/her to actually work on it to improve. But still, that's harsh way to teach them if they are new. We hope they read before they write, but they don't.

Comment: @Frederik.L That is an interesting meta post, just there is a problem with defining what a "bad" post is. If I see OP spent time on writing a pattern, found out it does not work, what with, what is expected, and - what is important - it is not easy to google the exact problem, it is not a bad question. Still, our comments are off-topic, we'll need to delete them, I guess.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Question-DVers might suspects that OP didn't craft the regex as you suspect, but found it somewhere on the internet (or in their codebase) and now drops it to us to adjust it for their (new?) needs. I personally didn't vote and I have no idea who's right or wrong here.

Comment: @SebastianProske Judging by the OP regex quality, it was really crafted by OP :) Again, just my gut feeling.

Answer (score -1):

Though you did not specify exactly what you are trying to do, here you can try the following regex :

```
\b\d{6}-\d{4}\b|\b\d{4}\b|\b\d{6}\b
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I want the code to find the numbers like

100282 1187
100282-1187

Comment: But also with other numbers. So the regex code should find xxxxxx xxxx and xxxxxx-xxxx